# How to create a query from a menu tree using RECURSIVE CTE?

Tags: sql-server

[SQL DEMO FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca11a/1)

Hello,
I need to create a query from a menu tree like this:

```
  **[+] Menu_1**

.....[+] Sub_Menu_1

  **[+] Menu_2**

.....[+] Sub_Menu_2

..........[+] Sub_Sub_Menu_2

  **[+] Menu_3**
```

I need to write a query that will return this order:

```
Name
-----
Menu_1
-------
..... Sub_Menu_1
-------
Menu_2
-------
..... Sub_Menu_2
-------
..........Sub_Sub_Menu_2
-------
Menu_3
-------
```

How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: I see similar examples in internet, with sql, but thank you.

Comment: You can do this using `Recursive CTE`. But I will suggest to do this in App code

Comment: The only way round this would be to have a helper function. You OK with that?

Comment: I know that is posible to do this using  **Recursive CTE** , but I can´t get the right query for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is like so:

```
WITH MenuCTE (IdMenu, IdParentMenu, ParentMenu, Name, Lvl)
AS
(
    -- Anchor member
    SELECT m.IdMenu, m.IdParentMenu, CAST('' AS varchar) AS ParentMenu, m.Name, 0 AS Lvl
    FROM dbo.Menus AS m
    WHERE CAST(m.IdParentMenu AS INT) = 0
    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive member
    SELECT m.IdMenu, m.IdParentMenu, CAST(mc.Name AS varchar) AS ParentMenu, m.Name, Lvl + 1 AS Lvl
    FROM dbo.Menus AS m
    INNER JOIN MenuCTE AS mc
        ON CAST(m.IdParentMenu AS INT) = mc.IdMenu
)
SELECT IdMenu, IdParentMenu, ParentMenu, REPLICATE('...', Lvl) + Name
FROM MenuCTE
--WHERE Lvl > 0
ORDER BY IdParentMenu
GO
```

The final display style is up to you (ordering and breadcrumb separators etc).

Recommended further reading: [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions in Microsoft TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)